# DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL Log diagnosis Win10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

Observed BSOD and DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL error message.  As I understand it, drivers are causing the problem: if this is true then the next question is which driver(s)?  **Is there a log or similar data to narrow down the device driver(s)?**

This HP laptop is a Win10 install from USB drive, not an upgrade from Win7.  I do  have copies of the OEM Win7 drivers that I can replace Win10 drivers: this would require understanding (diagnosing) which device drivers are causing the problem first.  **If there is better strategy: I look forward to constructive responses and diagnostic questions.**

Comment: analyze the dmp files from C:\windows\minidump or better the C:\windows\memory.dmp with Windbg: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Answer (score 0):

Normally a memory dump is created in C:\Windows after a crash. Analyze that with a free debugger like WinDbg to see the culprit driver (See [WhoCrashed](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/analyze-windows-memory-dump-files) or [WinDbg](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/315263)).

Normally the blue screen itself names the driver. (A file with .sys as the extension)

PS: I personally don't like people saying "Need constructive responses" since I know people here are trying to help and not waste yours or their own time.

Comment: The comment regarding the driver name on the BSOD is very helpful.  When I see the BSOD I will quickly hone-in on the .sys filename.  Thank you    In an ideal world, there would be a text file that names the offending driver